# playing online videos using DLNA

Tags: video, streaming, dlna

Is it possible to play online videos on a Digital Media Renderer from online media servers
(like vimeo) and control it from a phone without the use of any additional server (DLNA server or HTTP Server)?

I am not sure if it is possible to play the video by pointing the URI to the online content. I understand DLNA server is required for playing local content from phone, whether the same is applicable for playing online content also?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, I use X-DLNA (free app) for macOS.

It has an embedded internet browser to find videos online and play them via any DLNA device.

https://www.xdlna.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Flipps, an android app, can play videos by pointing the URI to their servers, which are not on the private network.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bianor.ams&hl=fr_FR

You can test with this URI :`http://46.4.107.92:8080/app/VzoiD06Hg4rfKGOF6NhmXK0grQ04OzAKSW0RHneMcm.`

It is one of their free videos.
Some renderers can't resolve domain name, try with an IP, like above.